# How to retrieve the client's machine name from within a WCF Operation Contract?

Tags: c#, wcf, operationcontext

I'm currently looking at the OperationContect.Current properties.  Is there a (nested) property the will always return the machine name of the client?  I'm currently using net.tcp binding, but would like to support additional bindings in the future.

Using .NET 3.5 SP1

Comment: Unless you send the caller's machine name as a WCF header, you won't be able to retrieve it

Comment: With machine name you mean the fully qualified domain as registered in the domain name server for the ip-address?

Comment: Preferably the fully qualified domain name, but what is classically known as the netbios name will suffice for my needs.

Comment: To clarify, this is all within the same domain.  I am not expecting this to be used in a public service.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the remote endpoint's IP address from the current OperationContext's IncomingMessageProperties, eg:

```
RemoteEndpointMessageProperty messageProperty = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
Console.WriteLine("Remote address is: {0}", messageProperty.Address);
```

Comment: +1 technically that is not the name but this was also my first guess. Could add a dns lookup....

Comment: Yeah, I don't think WCF encodes the full hostname in requests (it's not necessary to function, and would just add overhead). A reverse DNS lookup may work as long as there's no NAT between them.

Comment: I am getting server name where I am hosting my service like localhost:5555