# How to get Client's computer name from WCF asmx C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web, asmx

How to get Client's computer name from WCF asmx C#?

I have tried this way but it doesn't work at all.

1. This is a best solution that I've thought of but it doesn't work ... okay the result is to return the Client's computer name but sometimes it returns Computer name A and sometimes it's Computer name B.

   ```
   string[] computer_name = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(
      HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["remote_addr"])
        .HostName.Split(new Char[] { '.' });
   logData.ComputerName = computer_name[0].ToString();
   ```
2. The result is Computer name from WCF not Client.

   ```
   System.Environment.MachineName
   ```
3. The same result as 1 but returns `Empty` sometime.

   ```
   System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName("LocalHost").HostName.
   ```
4. Returns `Null`.

   ```
   OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name
   ```
5. Return IP,IP and Client's user

   ```
    loginRequest.ServerVariables["remote_addr"],
    Request.ServerVariables["remote_host"],
    Request.ServerVariables["remote_user"]
   ```

Comment: Is the client machine on the same network as the client machine?

Comment: Check this link if it helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034660/how-to-retrieve-the-clients-machine-name-from-within-a-wcf-operation-contract

Comment: This *may* be doable in an intranet context. Not possible on the internet. What context are you working in and *what do you plan to do with this information*?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I assume that OP works in scope of domain as it is hard to imagine the scenarios for using machine name in the internet solutions

Comment: @Alex - are you new around here? (joking - slightly. I have seen plenty of questions where people are seeking bizarre information like this (or MAC addresses) and expecting them to work in Internet situations. I find it's best to check what the expectations are explicitly)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Your truth, maybe it is really worth to check this)))

Comment: @Kenneth K-Yes. Same network and Thanks for your help guys :)

Answer (score 1):

You can enable WCF service to access ASP.Net http context and get the address from the context:

```
<system.serviceModel>            
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
...
</system.serviceModel>
```

After this you'll be able to access **HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress** property to get sender details

Comment: Thank u so much Alex, Let's me try :)

Comment: Where should i push your code in? Is it web.config? This is my web.config code.....
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <appSettings/>
 <connectionStrings/>
 <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"></compilation>
  <authentication mode="Forms"/>
  <webServices>
   <protocols>
    <remove name="HttpSoap12"/>
   </protocols>
  </webServices>
  <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: @OffThanapol see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731354(v=vs.110).aspx